# I accidentally copied duplicate pictures from someone's timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

How do I delete duplicate photos on my timeline?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there's much you can do except go in and manually choose which ones to delete. Facebook does have the ability for you to "mass delete" photos, so at least you won't have to do them one by one. As far as automatically searching for and removing duplicates, afraid that's not possible.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever try to delete the duplicates, its a bug and its just the thumbnail of the picture that's getting cloned, not the picture file. If you try deleting thinking its a duplicate you might endup deleting the actual files from the folder.

Just Pick Hide, not Delete. It hides one of them.

Now it have been solved by Facebook.

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=637232319636745)